# Angular routing always access root level url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using **[fountainjs](http://fountainjs.io)** to generate my angular1 boilerplate with ui-router to control the routing.

During the development, my app run without problem, but the problem lies when I try to run the result of the gulp build (dist) to my apache server, where I put it under sub folder `my-site/my-angular-app`, the routing always try to access the root level domain, means it accessing non-existence js, style and asset files.

I've played around with using `<base href="/">` and enable/disable the html5 mode but still the problem persist. Would like to know if anyone has ever encountered the same problem and found solution for it?

Comment: With HTML5 mode disabled, it should *"just work"*. With it enabled, you need to set the base URI correctly, eg `<base href="/my-site/my-angular-app/">`. Also, you need server-side URL rewriting for HTML5 mode to work correctly

Comment: you are right... I guess I have to live with the hash now